# How to block Windows phone build in phonegap

Tags: phonegap-build

I don't want windows phone build when i pull latest code in the phonegap site. I want only `Android` Build. I have attached the screen shot.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select target platforms in your configuration file.
To build for Android only, add this line to your **config.xml**:

```
<gap:platform name="android" />
```

[Related PhoneGap documentation page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/config_ref_pgb_config.md.html#Configuring%20Remote%20Builds_specifying_platforms)